# DCGAN generating just noise

Tags: python, deep-learning, noise, loss, dcgan

I am trying to train DCGAN on the ["Labeled Faces in the Wild"](http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/lfw/) dataset with image shape (64,64,3). After training for 1000 or more epochs it is generating just noise. 
The code is as follows:

```
class GAN():

img_rows = 64
img_cols = 64
channels = 3

optimizer_G = Adam(0.0002, 0.5)
optimizer_D = Adam(0.0002, 0.5)

def __init__(self):

    # Initialize 
    self.img_rows = img_rows
    self.img_cols = img_cols
    self.channels = channels
    self.img_shape = (self.img_rows, self.img_cols, self.channels)
    self.latent_dim = 100

    # Build the discriminator
    self.discriminator = self.build_discriminator()

    # Build the generator
    self.generator = self.build_generator()

    # The generator takes noise as input and generates imgs
    z = Input(shape=(100,))
    img = self.generator(z)

    # For the combined model we will only train the generator
    self.discriminator.trainable = False

    # The discriminator takes generated images as input and determines validity
    validity = self.discriminator(img)

    # The combined model  (stacked generator and discriminator)
    # Trains the generator to fool the discriminator
    self.combined = Model(inputs=z, outputs=validity)
    self.combined.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer_G)


def build_generator(self):

    input_shape = (self.img_rows, self.img_cols, self.channels)
    mom=0.8

    generator = Sequential()
    generator.add(Dense(units= 512*4*4, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', input_dim=100))
    generator.add(Reshape(target_shape=(4, 4, 512)))
    generator.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.5))
    generator.add(Activation('relu'))

    generator.add(Conv2DTranspose(filters=256, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same',
                                  data_format='channels_last',
                                  kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    generator.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=mom))
    generator.add(Activation('relu'))

    generator.add(Conv2DTranspose(filters=128, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same',
                                  data_format='channels_last',
                                  kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    generator.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=mom))
    generator.add(Activation('relu'))

    generator.add(Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same',
                                  data_format='channels_last',
                                  kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    generator.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=mom))
    generator.add(Activation('relu'))

    generator.add(Conv2DTranspose(filters=3, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same',
                                  data_format='channels_last',
                                  kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    generator.add(Activation('tanh'))
    print("Generator: ")
    generator.summary()

    # optimizer = Adam(lr=0.00015, beta_1=0.5)
    generator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer_D, metrics=None)

    return generator

def build_discriminator(self):
    drp = 0.5
    mom=0.8

    discriminator = Sequential()
    discriminator.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same',
                             data_format='channels_last',
                             kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                             input_shape=self.img_shape))
    discriminator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    discriminator.add(Dropout(drp))

    discriminator.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same',
                             data_format='channels_last',
                             kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    discriminator.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=mom))
    discriminator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    discriminator.add(Dropout(drp))

    discriminator.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same',
                             data_format='channels_last',
                             kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    discriminator.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=mom))
    discriminator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    discriminator.add(Dropout(drp))

    discriminator.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same',
                             data_format='channels_last',
                             kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    discriminator.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=mom))
    discriminator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    discriminator.add(Dropout(drp))

    discriminator.add(Flatten())
    discriminator.add(Dense(1))
    discriminator.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
    print("Discriminator: ")
    discriminator.summary()

    # optimizer = Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5)
    discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer_D, metrics=['accuracy'])

    return discriminator

def load_data(self):
    path = 'faces1'

    num_samples=len(os.listdir(path))
    print(num_samples)
    imlist = os.listdir(path)

    immatrix = np.array([np.array(Image.open(path + '/' + im2).resize((img_rows, img_cols))).flatten() for im2 in imlist], 'f')
    label=np.ones((num_samples,),dtype = int)
    label[0:] = 0      
    train_data = [immatrix,label]
    nb_classes = 2 

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train_data[0], train_data[1], test_size=0.1, random_state=4)
    X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, channels)
    X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, channels)
    X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
    X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
    X_train /= 255
    X_test /= 255

    print('X_train shape:', X_train.shape)
    print(X_train.shape[0], 'train samples')

    Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
    Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)

    return X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test

def train(self, epochs, batch_size=128, sample_interval=50):

    # Load the dataset
    X_train, _, _, _ = self.load_data()

    # Rescale -1 to 1
    X_train = X_train / 127.5 - 1.
    # print(X_train.shape," 1")
    # X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=3)
    # print(X_train.shape," 2")
    # print(X_train)

    # Adversarial ground truths
    valid = np.ones((batch_size, 1))
    fake = np.zeros((batch_size, 1))

    d_loss_all, g_loss_all = [], []

    for epoch in range(epochs):

        #  Train Discriminator

        # Select a random batch of images
        idx = np.random.randint(0, X_train.shape[0], batch_size)
        imgs = X_train[idx]
        # print(idx)

        noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (batch_size, 100))

        # Generate a batch of new images
        gen_imgs = self.generator.predict(noise)

        # Train the discriminator

        d_loss_real = self.discriminator.train_on_batch(imgs, valid)
        d_loss_fake = self.discriminator.train_on_batch(gen_imgs, fake)
        d_loss = 0.5 * np.add(d_loss_real, d_loss_fake)

        #  Train Generator

        noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (batch_size, 100))

        # Train the generator (to have the discriminator label samples as valid)
        g_loss = self.combined.train_on_batch(noise, valid)

        d_loss_all.append(d_loss[0])
        g_loss_all.append(g_loss)
        # Plot the progress
        print ("%d [D loss: %f, acc.: %.2f%%] [G loss: %f]" % (epoch, d_loss[0], 100*d_loss[1], g_loss))

        # If at save interval => save generated image samples
        if epoch % sample_interval == 0:
            self.sample_images(epoch)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    plt.plot(d_loss_all, label='Discriminator', alpha=0.5)
    plt.plot(g_loss_all, label='Generator', alpha=0.5)
    plt.title("Training Losses")
    plt.legend()
    if epoch == 0:
      plt.legend()
    plt.pause(0.0000000001)
    plt.show()
    plt.savefig('trainingLossPlot.png')

def sample_images(self, epoch):
    r, c = 5, 5
    noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (r * c, 100))
    gen_imgs = self.generator.predict(noise)

    # Rescale images 0 - 1
    gen_imgs = 0.5 * gen_imgs + 0.5

    fig, axs = plt.subplots(r, c)
    cnt = 0
    for i in range(r):
        for j in range(c):
            axs[i,j].imshow(gen_imgs[cnt, :,:,0], cmap='gray')
            axs[i,j].axis('off')
            cnt += 1
    fig.savefig("images/%d.png" % epoch)
    plt.show()
    plt.close()

gan = GAN()
gan.train(epochs=1000, batch_size=128, sample_interval=100)
```

The loss plot is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxblr.png)

The generated images after 1000 epochs are [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8tXr.png)

The loss is converging of both generator and discriminator still noise is being produced. What tweaks needs to be done?

Comment: Did you ever find out the source of this problem? I'm dealing with the same problem and not sure as to why it's happening.

https://github.com/xtr33me/TensorFlow-LiveLessons/blob/master/notebooks/demo_gan.ipynb

Comment: Your results are not just noise. At least there's something generated. Mine is just noise. Have you tried training for more epochs ?

Comment: Yea I had left it overnight to train and just had noise in the end as well...or rather the results were noisy :)  That said, I did find the source to my problem, however it doesn't seem to be the same thing for you.  It was the activation assignment in my dsicriminator call to Dense as well as my generators call to Conv2D.  By not passing "sigmoid" as the activation param in the call to Conv2D and Dense and adding it on the following line in its own call to Activation, I was able to resolve the issue as you can see in the results now posted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `gen_imgs[cnt, :,:,0].astype(np.uint8)` in imshow()?
If it's not that it might be the network design...

Good luck!

Comment: Yes i have done this in code. It is not working. IDK what's wrong with the architecture.